# Grails Facebook Plugin - How to Handle Invalid User

Tags: facebook, grails, plugins, filter

I am using the wonderful [Grails Facebook Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-facebook) and things are working alright. The problem comes from the fact that I provide another way to authenticate: forms authentication. If there is already a user in the system with the email address of the Facebook user, I would like to gracefully alert the user of this fact. I don't know how to do that since I am buried inside of a service which gets called from a Filter. Ideally I would like to show an error message on the login page. Is this possible?

Inside my `FacebookAuthService`:

```
    FacebookUser create(FacebookAuthToken token) {
    log.info("Create domain for facebook user $token.uid")

    Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(token.accessToken.accessToken)
    FacebookProfile fbProfile = facebook.userOperations().userProfile
    String email = fbProfile.getEmail() 

    String emailMatch = User.findByEmailAddress(email)

    if(emailMatch != null)
        throw new RuntimeException("username is bad!!")
```

I want to display this error message to the user instead of the exception trickling all the way through. How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put this message into a flash object:

```
def grailsWebRequest = WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest()
def flash = grailsWebRequest.attributes.getFlashScope(request)
flash.error = "username is bad!!!"
return null // Facebook filter will skip authorization at this case
```

Also, instead of `RuntimeException` it's better to use instance of `AuthenticationException`. At this case you can configure Spring Security to redirect to special url after exception. Just put into `Config.groovy`:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.failureHandler.exceptionMappings = [
   'MyException': '/usernameIsBad'
]
```

Comment: Thanks Igor. I have a couple of outstanding questions. Can we do a chat?